# Is it possible to output a value (feature class) along specific increments along a given route?

Tags: qgis, land-classification

I have a .shp file of a route (ie., the route of a cable) and a .shp file of the various sediment classifications covering the entire area of the route.

I was wondering if it was possible for QGIS to output the sediment classification along 1 meter increments along the cable route into an attribute table?

I've seen that you could possibly use 'array_find' but I'm not sure if QGIS is smart enough to look up the type of sediment found at, for example, 57 meters along this route.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from a route (line) and class (polygons) layers.

You can use the Processing Toolbox to :

1. generate points along the route with `Points along geometry`, this generates an 'Interpolated points' layer
2. find the class it belongs to with `Join attributes by location`

The resulting layer is made of points interpolated along the route, with a distance from start attribute and a class attribute

Input Data layers:
[image]

Create points:
[image]

Join attributes:
[image]

View results:
[image]

[image]